# What are the reasons to avoid anonymous types in XML Schema

Tags: xsd

I wonder, if there are other reasons to avoid anonymous types in XML Schema besides the possibility to reuse the type and to make life easier for code generation tools? (These two reasons are explained in http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-avoid-anonymous-types/ and https://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/section_2_3_1-Hints-on-Writing-XML-Schemas.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In broad terms, that's about it. To me though, the problem is in the details regarding the reuse (what kind, why, the author vs. consumer) and the tool in discussion (what is it for, would anonymous vs. named really make a difference, etc.)

The "reuse" aspects exhibited in the attached links is definitely very limited. I could still achieve reuse, based on the article's samples, by using anonymous types with named groups for the content model.

Type hierarchies (derivation) through extension is another form of reuse. Yet, it is different than what was suggested in that article, since it talks to OO principles. Then you have derivation through restriction, which many "disgruntled" practitioners would argue is not reuse... yet, it requires a named type.

A recursive structure (another way of reusing) is not possible with anonymous declarations; One way to achieve a recursive data structure is through use of complex type. (The other way is through ref of a global element.)

None of the above links speaks about redefinition (for reasons related to how some chose to shun the concept). While a redefine for types is ultimately some sort of derivation (therefore it requires a named schema component), it is also an extremely powerful mechanism to convert/transform extensible and generic models into specific and more usable ones, specific to an adopter; ultimately, allowing to elegantly maintain an XSD-based "diffgram" between different, but related, models.

Anonymous types are also mentioned in authoring styles; so contrasting the Salami Slice vs. the Venetian Style could provide you with additional insight; search it or start [here](http://www.xfront.com/GlobalVersusLocal.html) (I am not affiliated with it, nor consider it complete, but it is a good start).